# Config BackupPC on Linux: printenv script 500 error

Tags: linux

I'm configuring BackupPC on a Linux box and can run the BackupPC_Admin cgi. But when I try to access a machine I get the 'Only privileged users can...' message.

So I checked the documentation and I should be able to run the printenv cgi, but when I do I get a 500 error.

The documentation doesn't go that far, and hopefully a Linux guru can assist me.

Comment: 500 is internal server error, and should have some more info about it within the server's error_log

Comment: The errors I'm getting are (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/srv/httpc/cgi-bin/printenv' filed and Premature end of script header: printenv

Comment: I figured out my issue if anyone cares or has a similar problem. I was missing a configuration line in Apaches httpd.conf. Where I wasn't properly specifying the authentication files. First time I've had to do anything like this. I'm surprised it went as smoothly as it did aside from this faux pas.